# RequireJS or JQuery seem to be caching data

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I have a module like this:

```
define([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        email: $('#email').val() //$('#email') is a html input box
    };
});
```

From a page that requires this module when I run

```
var Form= require('src/form');
Form.email;
```

It will get the correct value, however, if I enter a new email address it keeps getting the original value and it does not update.

If I change to the following, it works:

```
define([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        email: $('#email');
    };
});
```

...

```
var Form= require('src/form');
Form.email.val();
```

It seems to me that RequireJs is only evaluating the returned object once.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form module will only return the value of `$('#email')` at the time the module is loaded; setting `$('#email').val()` to a variable stores it by value and not by reference to the element's value.

You would have to keep your update and return `$('#email')` which caches the jQuery selector, so that you can find its value at each time in point you want to look it up.

To avoid exposing the jQuery selector, use encapsulation through a closure and create a getter method within your module:

```
 define([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
   'use strict';
   var $email = $('#email');

   return {
     getEmail: function() {
       return $email.val();
     }
   }
 });
```

And then use `Form.getEmail()` to retrieve the value

Comment: Is there someway to tell requirejs to use byVal for the value?  The reason is I don't want the state of the object to be modifiable via the Form module (deliberately or accidentally).  So I only want the client to have access to the value of the control.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that RequireJs is only evaluating the returned object once. Does anyone know what is going on here?

The behaviour is the same in both scenarios; requirejs caches the returned object. The only difference is in what is being returned.

In the first scenario, a string value is returned (and cached); it has no reference to the input field any more, so any changes will not be reflected.

In the second scenario, a reference to a jQuery result set is returned; this object has kept its reference to the input field and so calling `.val()` on that will always return the most recent value.

Answer (score 0):

According to requirejs documentation:

> Modules in RequireJS are an extension of the Module Pattern, with the benefit of not needing > globals to refer to other modules.
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Like in the module pattern the `define()` function is only called once to initialise the module. So this:

```
return {
    email: $('#email').val() //$('#email') is a html input box
};
```

it's called once even when you call `require()` multiple times.

You can have more info about the module pattern [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)